# Github for Windows XP

Tags: windows, github

I know rarely anyone use Windows XP, but due to some circumstances I still use it. The problem is I want to use the desktop version of Github on XP but it requires Windows 7.
Please can anyone suggest me a way.
Please don't tell me to upgrade since I can't.

Comment: use the commandline tools.

Comment: If a program requires Windows 7 or later there's very little you can do to run it on older versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this download](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Not sure if this will execute for Windows XP, but give it a try.